# Is there a Function type in C#?

Tags: c#, function, types

I like to know if in C# there is a Function type like in AS3 for example. I would like to do somnthing like this (but in C#):

```
private function doSomething():void {
    // statements
}

var f:Function = doSomething
f()
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, they're called delegates in .NET, not function types.

You use the reserved keyword `delegate` to define new ones, and there's plenty that are predefined in the class libraries.

To define one that matches your example:

```
public delegate void DoSomethingDelegate(Object param1, Object param2);
```

Then to assign it:

```
DoSomethingDelegate f = DoSomething;
f(new Object(), new Object());
```

There's also two generic types of delegate types defined in the base class library, one for methods that return a value, and one for those who doesn't, and they come with variations over how many arguments you have.

The two are `Func<..>` for methods that return a value, and `Action<..>` for methods that doesn't.

In your case, this would work:

```
Action<Object, Object> f = DoSomething;
f(new Object(), new Object());
```

Note that in this last case, you don't have to declare `DoSomethingDelegate`.

Comment: Func and Action are heavily used in Linq.

Comment: The problem is one cannot create its own Func implementation, so that does not quite cut it, sadly.

Comment: Func<int, bool> myFunc = myobject.FuncOfIntThatReturnsABool ?

Answer (score 8):

The concept of [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e.aspx) in .NET are exactly what you are looking for.

There are examples on the linked page, as well as many tutorials and in-depth explanations of how they are implemented and used. Google away!

Answer (score 6):

They (references to functions) are called delegates

Here's a wonderful primer: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html

Comment: They're complete classes in the background, which constructors accept a function, but C# 2 and 3 have sugared that fact completely away, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are type safe function pointers called [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(VS.80).aspx).  For example ...

```
void Main()
{
   object o1 = new object();
   object o2 = new object();

   Action<object, object> act = DoSomething;
   act( o1, o2 );
}

private void DoSomething( object o1, object o2 )
{
  // do that thang
}
```

`Action<T>` is the built in delegate ...

```
public delegate void Action<T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
```

There are also anonymous functions called [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).  For example ...

```
   List<int> lst = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
   var res = lst.Where( l => l > 3 );
```

The argument to the Where method is a Lambda Expression.  Check out Eric White's blog for a great discussion on this stuff: [Query Composition Using Functional Programming Techniques in C# 3.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/FP-Tutorial.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for a C# delegate type.

```
    delegate void DoSomethingDelegate(object obj1, object obj2);

    void DoSomething(object a, object b)
    {
    }

    void RunDoSomething()
    {
        //use your delegate
        DoSomethingDelegate d = new DoSomethingDelegate(DoSomething);
        d(new object(), new object());

        //alernatively, use the built in generic version
        Action<object, object> d2 = new Action<object, object>(DoSomething);
        d2(new object(), new object());

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

[Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-7.0) type was added since **c# 9 and .Net 5.0**. Delegates are not required anymore for this basic usage:

```
var f:Func<TResult> = doSomething;
```